# Is there evidence that it's unwise to have many required fields on a form?

Tags: forms

I am looking for some confirmation.. research or article or otherwise.. that having forms with a whole host of required fields that are not strictly necessary to communicating the data/message the user is trying to submit will turn people off of bothering to submit it.  I know there's mention of this in Steve Krug's 'Don't Make Me Think' book, but I'd like something I can link to if possible!

Comment: I would only put needed info on a form. Why make the user think about something that is not necessary? If it is really optional, put it elsewhere in the workflow. I guess this would mean that all fields on a form would be "required" for the function that the form was per-forming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each case is different, but in general the more required fields you have on a form the higher the likelihood that your user will get frustrated (aka form fatigue).

If you have a specific page you are vetting, i'd recommend doing an A/B test. Variant A has all the required fields, variant B has the minimum set - see which form converts better, then make a decision.

Comment: +1 for real-world testing of your exact scenario.  That said, I'm willing to bet right now that the one with less required fields wins.

Answer (score 5):

You should read up on forms at [Luke Wroblewskis website](http://www.lukew.com/ff/). It is full of good information on the subject and I consider his book [Web form design: filling in the blanks](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/webforms/) an invaluble source of knowledge for most questions like yours.